# How to use OpenGL ES 2.0 extensions from java in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get to the PVRTC extension to load compressed textures in my game. I know that this extension is supported on many devices but what I can't find is how can I query for it and use it in my application. I see that OpenGL ES 1.0 and 1.1 both have Ext classes but I can't find it for the OpenGL ES 2.0. Any ideas about how can I load a compressed PVR texture from Java?

Answer (score 0):

The ICS source contains the ES 2 extension header file from Khronos at various places, one is `ICS/frameworks/base/opengl/include/GLES2`. Perhaps it is possible to create a small JNI binding to these functions.